# When Jodahs is morphing to different forms, are those from past species?

Tags: liliths-brood

At one point in Imago, Jodahs is drifting through different physical forms: aquatic, scaled, four legged, etc.  Are these based on species that the Oankali traded with in the past?  Or just random biological drift?

Answer (score 3):

Although it isn't said specifically in the book, the Oankali do mention having traded with many, many other species and possibly the traits were from others they had crossbred with.

In "Adulthood Rites", the second book, it says that the default form is the huge, blind, deaf, caterpillar-like Akjai and that when they came to earth, "they used their long memories and vast store of genetic material to construct speaking, hearing, bipedal children. Children they hoped would seem more acceptable to Human tastes. The spoken language, an ancient revival, has been built in genetically.".

Jodahs also mentions during the period of uncontrollable changes that it wandered around, "tasting" (genetically sampling) the Earth it feared it would be taken from. Without a Human mate to shape it to their desires, it's likely Jodahs was taking on the traits of animals it was sampling.